# Shell script to download info about movies from imdb/thmb and putting it into an .nfo file for per-use

Tags: debian, shell-script, multimedia

Does anybody know of a tool which will extract info from `imdb.com`/`themoviedb.org` and dumping it into a text file? I have been searching but with no luck.

I usually get the movie name but want to have the plot, actors' names, keywords whatever info. Is there from `imdb.com`. If it's not possible from `imdb.com` then perhaps `themoviedb.org`?

Either of the above would be useful.

As of now I have to manually scrap the movie synopsis from the `imdb.com` site, create the `.nfo` file using mediainfo's `--LogFile` option.

Looking forward to make it easier and also down the road use more of the fields.

Comment: Have you tried wget or curl?

Comment: see wget or curl aren't really the answers. wget or curl will just download the webpage. What I need is some sort of structured data so that I can put in some form of metadata either as an .nfo file or in the media file itself so that later I can know at a glance what the movie is about, who acts in it and things like that even without the launching the movie itself.

It could even be beneficial while searching as well. I don't know of a similar solution as of date.

Comment: I don't think you can find something like that, since every page is different and structured differently. It would be easier to download the pages and process them by yourself.

Comment: themoviedb have an api you can use together with curl/wget: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Answer (score 1):

In this case I personally wouldn't reinvent the wheel and just use imdb-api (node.js) or some php imdb fetcher library. You could of course integrate those tools into your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the data from IMDB to your computer from: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces and parse it any way you want :)

Comment: The FTP data files are the only authorized source. See http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware. *You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar online data gathering and extraction tools on our website*

Comment: I know that imdb.com discourages this sort of behavior, that's why I had shared themoviedb.org which actually has Apps. and shared an API so people could use it to retrieve the data any way you want it.